# amsmath error: Multiple \label's: label 'xxx' will be lost

Tags: amsmath

This is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcounter{rulec}
\renewcommand\therulec{R\arabic{rulec}}
\newcommand\trule[1]{\refstepcounter{rulec}\label{r:#1}\therulec: }
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
& \trule{foo} Foo \\
& \trule{bar} Bar \\
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

I'm getting:

```
! Package amsmath Error: Multiple \label's: label 'r:foo' will be lost.

See the amsmath package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.12 \end{split}
```

What's wrong and how to fix?

Comment: the point of `equation/split` (or better `equation/aligned`) is to have a single `\label` for the entire display and `amsmath` goes to some effort to make that posible even though `\label` may be in any column of the alignment. So it  would be far more natural to use `align` here

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You cannot have two distinct `\label` commands in the same `split` environment.

The `amsmath` package tweaks `\label` to fulfill its needs, so it is redefined inside the alignment environments. But there's still its original version available as `\ltx@label`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcounter{rulec}
\renewcommand\therulec{R\arabic{rulec}}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\trule[1]{\refstepcounter{rulec}\ltx@label{r:#1}\textup{\therulec: }}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\ref{r:foo}, \ref{r:bar}

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
& \trule{foo} Foo \\
& \trule{bar} Bar
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks! However, when I add `\usepackage{cleveref}` to the mix, the `\ltx@label` stops working. Maybe you know a quick workaround or it's better to submit a new question?

Comment: @yegor256 With `cleveref` you need to use `\label@noarg` instead of `\ltx@label`.